# Occasional EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, crash, exc-bad-access

Every now and then, my app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing a Dictionary, although the object exists and has been accessed many times before the crash without any problem.

It is created at start of app with:

```
static var whiteLabelling = [String : String]()
```

and is never recreated afterwards.

Entries may be added, changed and removed at runtime, and, depending on the situation, it can run through a `FareEngine.whiteLabelling.removeAll()`

Multiple threads access it simultaneously as well without crashing.

What can be the reason for this occasional crash?
[image]

Comment: That error is usually a timing issues. Somewhere you are jumping threads or actors. You have to look into leaks and likely concurrency so you can organize stuff.

Comment: You are currently in "Thread 1". You have at least that one and Main Thread. I highly suspect concurrent access/write to it.

Comment: There are multiple threads reading this dictionary and one thread that occasionally writes to it. I am not aware that reading or writing to a dictionary would not be allowed from independent threads at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that you always read from the same thread.

You could use always main thread with a basic `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`. That way, it's always in the same queue (main thread/thread 0).

Another possible way would be using a private queue, ensuring it's always in that same queue.

- add a (private) property to `FareEngine`

```
static private var whiteLabellingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.yourApp.whiteLabellingQueue, qos: .userInitiated) //or any other `qos`
```

- Make `whiteLabelling` private (to ensure there is no more issue with other code accessing it):

```
private static var whiteLabelling: [String: String]
```

- Then, make access possible:

```
func setWhiteLabelling(value: String, forKey key: String) {
    whiteLabellingQueue.sync {
        self.whiteLabelling[key] = value
    }
}
```

- Finally, make writing possible:

```
func getWhiteLabelling(forKey key: String) -> String? {
    let value: String?
    whiteLabellingQueue.sync {
        value = self.whiteLabelling[key]
    }
    return value
}
```

Now, when you want to access the values:

```
let req = FareEngine.getWhiteLabelling(forKey: "GPSACCURACY")
```

Since, you can have a remove all, do the same:

```
func cleanWhiteLabelling() {
    whiteLabellingQueue.sync {
        self.whiteLabelling.removeAll()
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, looks promising. Although I am quite puzzled that concurrent access to a dictionary from different threads should cause problems